# Identifying stable periods of rises and falls in time series

Tags: time-series, structural-change

I have a time series (think of a stock price, for example) in which I would like to identify periods of rises and falls---periods when the series is generally increasing/decreasing. The time series is not necessarily stationary. Are there standard methods for doing this?

Comment: What about a hidden Markov model?

Comment: Hi @kjetilbhalvorsen, yes I suspect that some HMM model could be useful here, for example some adaptation of Kleinberg's burstiness model (https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/bhs.pdf). But that model is adapted for binary occurrences of words in documents/streams, and not to continuous time series data. This problem seems so general that I thought there must already be customized solutions for it.